# Writing out sparse matrix as a compressed gzip file

Tags: python, scipy

I have a sparse matrix `m` (scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) and a output path `p` (example `p="~/matrix.mtx.gz"`). I'm using `scipy.io.mmwrite` to write out `m` (to the path `p`), but it doesn't appear to have any compression options. Is there a way to write out the sparse matrix as a gzipped file in Matrix Market format? I don't want to save as a .mtx file and have to read in the file again to gzip it.

Comment: `scipy.io.mmwrite` accepts a "file-like object".  Thus, you should be able to import `gzip`, do `f = gzip.open('xxx.tgz','w')`, and pass that to `mmwrite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but this should work:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('matrix.mtx.gz', 'wb') as f:
    scipy.io.mmwrite(f, array)
```